# Sitecore - Rss feeds remove link

Tags: sitecore

Using SiteCore 6.5, and we want to remove the link from rss items (this is because they are just informational alerts and there isn't a page to link to).

In Feeds/Design for this alert template, I can enter a Title, Body, and Date but how do I remove the link? I guess I need to customise the alert RSS template somehow ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look with Dot Peek or Reflector to this class:

```
Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FeedRenderer
```

You have to create your own class where you copy above class and modify it.

On method RenderItem is called other method AddLink. Please remove it.

After on Sitecore Backend go to :

```
  /sitecore/layout/Renderings/System/Feeds/FeedRenderer
```

and modify next fields : Namespace,Tag,Assembly with your own values .

**UPDATE:**

I modify the class, it will inherits from FeedRender :

```
 public class CFeedRenderer : Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FeedRenderer
```

We need this change because on FeedDeliveryLayout we have above code, and it's checking in FeedManager if is type of FeedRenderer

```
try
  {
    this.Response.Output.Write(FeedManager.Render(FeedManager.GetFeed(obj).Render()));
  }
What I wrote first time is also correct .
```

This is my result of code :

```
      <rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
      <channel>
         <title>RSS Feed</title>
           <link>http://localhost/mylink.aspx</link>
           <description>dsds</description>
           <language>en</language>
         <item>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">{692ECF97-3443-4832244-8D56-54544343}</guid>
            <title>2</title>
            <description>B</description>
            <pubDate>Sat, 30 Nov 2013 21:24:25 +0100</pubDate>
          </item>
          <item>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">{B6330E10-D4B5-491B-AFB3-FB30484321AA}</guid>
            <title>3</title>
            <description>B</description>
            <pubDate>Sat, 30 Nov 2013 21:24:19 +0100</pubDate>
          </item>
     </channel>
   </rss>
```

Comment: Thanks... I'll give it ago and report back,

Comment: Ive followed your steps but the rss still seems to be using the original FeedRenderer control.. missing something ...

Comment: Excellent. I came to the same change of inheriting from FeedRenderer and it worked perfectly. Could you update your answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!